# Circularly polarized light passing through a polarizer

Tags: optics, polarization

Can anyone explain why the intensity of the incoming circularly polarized light is  same as it passes through a polarizer and comes out???

Comment: I might write an answer to learn more about the subject for myself, but this link looks pretty comprehensive.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Circular_polarizers   Apologies if you have  already read it, but you could then include the specific points you don't follow in your post.

Comment: What makes you think that the intensity stays the same?

Answer (score 1):

The intensity ***is*** changed when circularly polarized light passes through a polarizer, though. The light is changed from circularly polarized to linearly polarized. If you draw the evolution of the waves with respect to an axis, any part of the circularly polarized wave that is not aligned with the linear polarizer will have its intensity reduced.